# Jest Test: How to override imported helper function's call inside React component method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

In my React component, I have an instance method that calls an imported helper function. The current Jest test I am writing right now should not care about the call to that imported helper function inside the instance method. So how would I override that helper function's definition with something that really doesn't do anything?

**MyComponent:**

```
import { callSomeHelperFunction } from './some/where';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
  onSomethingChange(event) {
    // ...
    callSomeHelperFunction(data, this.props, name, etc);
    this.props.doWhatever();
  }
  ...
}
```

**Test:**

```
const onSomethingChange = jest.fn();
const component = shallow(
  <MyComponent ... onSomethingChange={onSomethingChange} />
);

const event = {};

// right here onSomethingChange is called, with first a call to
// callSomeHelperFunction(), but I really don't care about that.
// The test fails because some parameter is not provided to the
// helper function callSomeHelperFunction().

component.instance().onSomethingChange(event);
expect(onSomethingChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
```